# Combine two javascript/jquery codes into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

Im making a program to calculate the value of something.
anyone an idea how to couple two things?

This is what i have now, but doesn't work..

What is wrong ?
anyone an idea?
    
        
            Inboedelwaardemeter

```
               function checkTotal() {
                   var a =  document.querySelectorAll('input:checked'); 
                   var total = 0;
                   for(var x=0; x < a.length;x++){
                      total += a[x].value * 1072;
                   var resultaat= parseFloat(document.mijnForm5.getal18.value) + parseFloat(document.mijnForm5.getal19.value) 
                           + parseFloat(document.mijnForm5.getal20.value) + parseFloat(document.mijnForm5.getal21.value);
                   }
                  alert('Uw inboedelwaarde is €'+ (total + resultaat );
                }
        </script>
    </head> 
    <body>
    <center><h1>Inboedelwaardemeter</h1></center>
        <br>
        <b> Leeftijd hoofdkostwinner:</b>
        <form name="mijnForm1">
        <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal1" name="leeftijd"
                value="22" checked> 35 jaar en jonger
              <br>    
            <input type="radio" id="getal2" name="leeftijd"
                value="29"> 36 t/m 50 jaar
              <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal3" name="leeftijd"
                value="38"> 51 jaar en ouder
              <br>
            <br>
        <b> Samenstelling huishouden:</b>
        <br>
        <form name="mijnForm2">
            <input type="radio" id="getal4" name="huishouden"
                value="0" checked> Alleenstaande
              <br>    
            <input type="radio" id="getal5" name="huishouden"
                value="10"> Echtpaar / Samenwonende
              <br>
              <br>  
        <b> Netto maandinkomen hoofdkostwinner</b>
        <br>
        <form name="mijnForm3">
            <input type="radio" id="getal6" name="hoofdkostwinner"
                value="0" checked> Tot en met €1000,-
              <br>    
            <input type="radio" id="getal7" name="hoofdkostwinner"
                value="6"> €1001,- tot en met €2000,-
              <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal8" name="hoofdkostwinner"
                value="18"> €2001,- tot en met €3000,-
             <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal9" name="hoofdkostwinner"
                value="23"> €3001,- tot en met €4850
                  <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal10" name="hoofdkostwinner"
                value="23"> €4850,- of hoger
            <br>
            <br>
            <b> Oppervlakte woning</b>
            <br>
        <form name="mijnForm4">
            <input type="radio" id="getal11" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="0" checked> tot en met60m²
              <br>    
            <input type="radio" id="getal12" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="0"> 60m² tot en met 80m²
              <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal13" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="2">80m² tot en met 100m²
             <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal14" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="6"> 100m² tot en met 120m²
                  <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal15" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="8"> 120m² tot en met 150m²
                  <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal16" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="20"> 150m² t/m 200m²
                  <br>
            <input type="radio" id="getal17" name="Oppervlakte"
                value="23"> 200 m² en meer
            <br>
        </form>
        <form name="mijnForm5">
            <b>Heeft u meer dan €12.000 aan audiovisuele en computerapperatuur?
            <br>
            Zo ja, hoeveel? Zo nee, vul 0 in.
            <br>
            <input type="tekst" name="getal18" value="">
            <br>
            Heeft u meer dan €6.000 aan lijfsiraden?
            <br>
            Zo ja, hoeveel? Zo nee, vul 0 in.
            <br>
            <input type="tekst" name="getal19" value="">
            <br>
            Heeft u meer dan €15.000 aan bijzondere bezittingen?
            <br>
            Zo ja, hoeveel? Zo nee, vul 0 in.
            <br>
            <input type="tekst" name="getal20" value="">
            <br>
            Is het huurdersbelang meer dan €6.000?
            <br>
            Zo ja, hoeveel? Zo nee, vul 0 in.
            <br>
            <input type="tekst" name="getal21" value="">
            <br>
            </b>
        </form>
         <button onclick="checkTotal();">Bereken inboedelwaarde</button>
         <center>
             <img src="infofolio.gif" />
             <form action='indexinboedel.php' method='post'>
            <input type='submit' name='home' value='home'>
            </form></p>
         </center>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Thanks for replying!

Comment: What is the problem? And also I do not see any jQuery!

Comment: Put two JavaScript into one file and import it into your code. I don't understand your question what exactly your problem is ?

Comment: move the `var resultaat= ..` after the loop. close the } before the var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        var total1 = 0;
        $("[name='mijnForm5'] input").each(function(){
            total1 += parseFloat( $(this).val() );
        });

        var total2 = 0;
        $("input:checked").each(function(){
            total2 += $(this).val() * 1072;
        });

        alert("€ : " + total2 + total1);
    });
});
```

Comment: It's working but every awnser is now factor 10 to big...
Do you now why this is?

Comment: alert("Uw inboedelwaarde is € : " + parseFloat(total2 + total1));
Did this. Now its working!

Answer (score 0):

add `var resultaat= parseFloat.....` in the function above the `alert` call